# By two combinations of predictors in linear regression in R

Tags: r, linear-regression, lm

Suppose that I have `X1,...,X14` potential predictors.

Now for a given `Y` i want to make the OLS scheme:

```
Y~X1+X2
Y~X1+X3
 ....
Y~X1+X14
....
Y~X14+X13
```

which is basically all the by two combinations of all the predictors. After all those regressions are created I want to use them in the `predict` function (if possible).

My question is: How do i make all those regressions with all by two combinations of the regressors?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could also put them into formulas in one line like this:

```
mySpecs <- combn(letters[1:3], 2, FUN=function(x) reformulate(x, "Y"),
                 simplify=FALSE)
```

which returns a list that can be used in `lapply` to run regressions:

```
mySpecs
[[1]]
Y ~ a + b
<environment: 0x4474ca0>

[[2]]
Y ~ a + c
<environment: 0x4477e68>

[[3]]
Y ~ b + c
<environment: 0x447ae38>
```

You would then do the following to get a list of regression results.

```
myRegs <- lapply(mySpecs, function(i) lm(i, data=df))
```

Comment: Hello, I get this error when i run the first part: 'Error in matrix(r, nrow = len.r, ncol = count) : 
  'data' must be of a vector type, was 'language' '

Comment: Sorry. I had a typo and forgot to include the simplify=FALSE argument which returns a list in `combn` rather than simplifying to a matrix.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `combn` for all the combinations and then use an `apply` to create all the formulas:

```
#all the combinations
all_comb <- combn(letters, 2)

#create the formulas from the combinations above and paste
text_form <- apply(all_comb, 2, function(x) paste('Y ~', paste0(x, collapse = '+')))
```

Output

```
> text_form
  [1] "Y ~ a+b" "Y ~ a+c" "Y ~ a+d" "Y ~ a+e" "Y ~ a+f" "Y ~ a+g".....
```

Then you can feed the above formulas into your regression using `as.formula` to convert the texts into formulas (most likely in another `apply`).

Comment: can you please explain more..i am not sure how it works?

Comment: `combn` will create a matrix with all the 2-way combinations. Each column will contain a combination. Then we use `apply` which iterates over the columns in order to create the formulas. `paste` creates the text representing the formula. As you can see `text_form` has all the 2 way formulas represented as text. Using `text_form` to run the regressions would require an additional step as described in lmo's answer: `lapply(text_form, function(i) lm(i, data=df))`.